# Worse framerate with Object Pool

Tags: javascript, performance, reference, garbage-collection, premature-optimization

I am working on a game. And I have now read a couple of articles suggesting I should be re-using objects instead of creating new ones to reduce the frame drop when Garbage Collection sweeps in and removes objects.

Articles read on the subject:

1. [High-Performance, Garbage-Collector-Friendly Code](http://buildnewgames.com/garbage-collector-friendly-code/)
2. [Object Pools](http://beej.us/blog/data/object-pool/)
3. [Static Memory Javascript with Object Pools](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/static-mem-pools/)

However I am not getting the results that I want. Using an Object Pool is giving me worse framerates than just creating and destroying objects.
The one good news - besides learning - that I got out of this was that the tests not using Object Pools occasionally became unresponsive and crashed.

Why is that?

And how come I am not getting similar results as the people in those blogs?

---

- **Test 1** - *Using Arrays to hold the objects. Keeping reference by moving them in between two arrays.

  - [Using for loop to remove objects from array](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lqLgy/)
  - [Using indexOf to remove objects from array](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vBgqG/)
- **Test 2** - *Using an Array to hold the objects. Not keeping references.*

  **OCCASIONALLY CRASHES THE BROWSER:**

  - [Using for loop to remove objects from array](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CajLn/)
  - [Using indexOf to remove objects from array](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xIrdy/)
- **Test 3**

  - [Using Objects instead of Arrays to hold the objects. Keeping References.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GIfxq/)
- **Test 4**

  **OCCASIONALLY CRASHES THE BROWSER:**

  - [Using an Object instead of an Array to hold the objects. Not keeping references.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bflBA/)

---

*Please Edit if you think this can be improved.*

Answer (score 1):

Oh boy! I did it. Now I can answer my own question!

I read this article:
[How to write low garbage real-time Javascript](https://www.scirra.com/blog/76/how-to-write-low-garbage-real-time-javascript)

And it finally said click. 
All my previous code examples are using `Array.prototype.pop()` and `Array.prototype.slice()`
Both of those return objects. So I was still creating a lot of garbage.

Instead I realized I could just use one Array and move Objects around - never having to remove anything.

I extended the array object with a property: `.activeLength` and I was a happy camper.

"Removal" of objects:

```
function removeObject (object, pool) {
  var tempObj;
  for (var i = 0; i < pool.length; i++) {
    if ( pool[i] === object ) {
      pool.activeLength --;
      canvas.scene.remove( pool[i] );
      tempObj = pool[i]; 
      pool[pool[i]] = pool[pool.length - 1];
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm only moving objects around. And so I am not creating any garbage here. *(Three.js might though, since I am creating 3D objects with the Three.js Library);*

[Object Pool ~without~ Garbage](http://cdpn.io/EpazJ)